# forEach with spread operator returns undefined

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object of this type:

```
[{id: "somethin%g", apple: "dfgdf efd"}, ...]
```

I want to replace some special chars in values of key = `id` and not change anything else of the object.

So the example above, must be:

```
[{id: "something", apple: "dfgdf efd"}, ...]
```

I try this function:

```
function removeSpecialCharacters(metadata) {
  const result = metadata.forEach(datum => {
    const cleanId = datum.id.replace(/[.|&;$%@%"<>+]/g, '')
    return { ...datum, id: cleanId }
  })
  console.log(result)
  return result
}
```

I get `result = undefined`. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to replace the `forEach` by a `map`. `forEach` does not return an array. It simply runs the content of the loop and discards the results. Whereas `map` will create a second array and fill it with the mapped content.

```js
function removeSpecialCharacters(metadata) {
  const result = metadata.map(datum => {
    const cleanId = datum.id.replace(/[.|&;$%@%"<>+]/g, '')
    return { ...datum, id: cleanId }
  })
  return result
}

const data = [{id: "somethin%g", apple: "dfgdf efd"}];
console.log(removeSpecialCharacters(data));
```

Here is a shorter way to do this:

```js
function removeSpecialCharacters(metadata) {
  return metadata.map(datum =>
    ({ ...datum, id: datum.id.replace(/[.|&;$%@%"<>+]/g, '') })
  )
}

const data = [{id: "somethin%g", apple: "dfgdf efd"}];
console.log(removeSpecialCharacters(data));
```

See the [doc on map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on MDN.

Answer (score 0):

Because the return value of `forEach` is `undefined` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Return_value)). Use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead

Also, if you want only alphanumeric characters in your `id`, you could simply use this regex: `\W+`

`\W+` matches all the non-alphanumeric characters. Replace them with empty string.

```js
function removeSpecialCharacters(metadata) {
  const result = metadata.map(datum => {
    const cleanId = datum.id.replace(/\W+/g, '')
    return { ...datum, id: cleanId }
  })
  return result
}

const data = [{id: "someth+in%g#", apple: "dfgdf efd"},
              {id: 'some%@%"<>+#', apple: "dfgdf efd"}];
console.log(removeSpecialCharacters(data));
```